# Bootstrap toggle buttons not accessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I was trying to test implementation of the Bootstrap toggle button and something in the their js doesn't allow me to 'tab' to them with the keyboard. When I remove the js I can 'tab' to the checkbox just fine. Can anyone help me extend this so that I can 'tab' to each toggle button?

HTML

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
    Option one is enabled
  </label>
</div>
```

JS
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js

JSFIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/galnova/s2x57t2u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual `input` checkbox is hidden(`display: none`) behind the fancy `div.toggle-group`. This div is only made to look like a checkbox using CSS & toggled using JavaScript.

The fact is the checkbox is actually getting focused/tabbed in behind the scene, you just are not able to see it visually because its hidden.

If you need otherwise, you could write explicit JQuery to focus the outer element when the hidden checkbox is focused.

Here is the JQuery code which you need to include:

```
$( "input:checkbox" ).focus(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked') == true) {
    $(this).next('.toggle-group').find('.toggle-on').attr('tabindex', '-1').focus();
  } else {
    $(this).next('.toggle-group').find('.toggle-off').attr('tabindex', '-1').focus();
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how to write that?

Comment: yeah i did something like this recently. let me update

Comment: I'm thinking a :focus type something in the css for the toggle-group might work? Just not sure how to form it.

Comment: yes in the CSS you could have a style when focused but you need to "bring focus" to the element explicitly in the first place.

Comment: Ah...I'm not good at extending js functionality...do you know where I could look for an example of this in the wild?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/galnova/s2x57t2u/1/ I applied it and it didn't work.

Comment: Oops, one more minor important change, the checkbox cannot be `display: none`. display none cannot be focused. So override that. Check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s2x57t2u/3/)

Comment: You are truly brilliant. I can't toggle with the keyboard though. Hmmm. That should be native I thought.

Comment: Ya you would have to write keycode to toggle via keyboard.

Comment: I think I am going to defer to a dev to handle this...I'd have to come up with a click and a shift tab to go backwards which is well beyond my skillset. Thanks for helping me work through this though.

Comment: no worries .. accept the answer so it could help others as well.. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach

```
var $toggle = $('input:checkbox');
var $toggleDiv = $toggle.parent();
$toggleDiv.attr('tabindex','0');                // allow focus
$toggleDiv.unbind('keypress').keypress((e) => { // have enter trigger toggle
    if (e.which===13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newState = $toggle.is(':checked') ? 'off' : 'on';
        $toggle.bootstrapToggle(newState);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach...

```
$('.cb').bootstrapToggle();
$('.cb').each(function () {
    var $cb = $(this);
    var $toggleDiv = $cb.parent();
    $toggleDiv.attr('tabindex', '0');
    $toggleDiv.unbind('keypress').keypress((e) => {
        console.log(e.which);
        if (e.which === 13 || e.which === 32) {
            $toggleDiv.click()
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).